# Prove or Disprove the following statement. For any sets $A$, $ B$, and $C$, we have $A \cup (B \& C) = (A\cup B) \cup (A\&C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to figure this question out in my proofs class (tried venn-diagram the multiple set-notation signs are confusing me). Homework question in the fundamental sets unit.

Comment: It might help you to notice that $A \cap C \subset A$, hence $A \cup (A \cap C) = A$

Comment: We assume that $A \& B$ stay for $A \cap B$ ...

Comment: You must "unwind" the definitions : $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$ iff $x \in A$ **or** $x \in B \cap C$; in turn, $x \in B \cap C$ iff $x \in B$ **and** $x \in C$. Now "rearragne" the two conditions (written with "or" and "and") using De Morgan ...

Answer (score 0):

Since $A \cap C \subset A$ we get:
$$ (A \cup B)\cup(A \cap C) = A \cup B$$
On the other side we get:
$$ A \cup ( B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$$
So this equality is not universally true, consider: $A=\{1\} , \; B = \{2\} , \; C= \{3 \}$.